# My matrix multiplication program takes quadruple time when thread count doubles

Tags: multithreading, performance, optimization, openmp

I wrote this simple program that multiplies matrices.  I can specify how
many OS threads are used to run it with the environment variable
`OMP_NUM_THREADS`.  It slows down a lot when the thread count gets
larger than my CPU's physical threads.

Here's the program.

```
static double a[DIMENSION][DIMENSION], b[DIMENSION][DIMENSION],
    c[DIMENSION][DIMENSION];

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++)
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < DIMENSION; j++)
      for (unsigned k = 0; k < DIMENSION; k++)
        c[i][k] += a[i][j] * b[j][k];
```

My CPU is i7-8750H.  It has 12 threads.  When the matrices are large
enough, the program is fastest on around 11 threads.  It is 4 times as
slow when the thread count reaches 17.  Then run time stays about the
same as I increase the thread count.

Here's the results.  The top row is `DIMENSION`.  The left column is the
thread count.  Times are in seconds.  The column with `*` is when
compiled with `-fno-loop-unroll-and-jam`.

```
    1024    2048    4096    4096*   8192
1   0.2473  3.39    33.80   35.94   272.39
2   0.1253  2.22    18.35   18.88   141.23
3   0.0891  1.50    12.64   13.41   100.31
4   0.0733  1.13    10.34   10.70   82.73
5   0.0641  0.95    8.20    8.90    62.57
6   0.0581  0.81    6.97    8.05    53.73
7   0.0497  0.70    6.11    7.03    95.39
8   0.0426  0.63    5.28    6.79    81.27
9   0.0390  0.56    4.67    6.10    77.27
10  0.0368  0.52    4.49    5.13    55.49
11  0.0389  0.48    4.40    4.70    60.63
12  0.0406  0.49    6.25    5.94    68.75
13  0.0504  0.63    6.81    8.06    114.53
14  0.0521  0.63    9.17    10.89   170.46
15  0.0505  0.68    11.46   14.08   230.30
16  0.0488  0.70    13.03   20.06   241.15
17  0.0469  0.75    20.67   20.97   245.84
18  0.0462  0.79    21.82   22.86   247.29
19  0.0465  0.68    24.04   22.91   249.92
20  0.0467  0.74    23.65   23.34   247.39
21  0.0458  1.01    22.93   24.93   248.62
22  0.0453  0.80    23.11   25.71   251.22
23  0.0451  1.16    20.24   25.35   255.27
24  0.0443  1.16    25.58   26.32   253.47
25  0.0463  1.05    26.04   25.74   255.05
26  0.0470  1.31    27.76   26.87   253.86
27  0.0461  1.52    28.69   26.74   256.55
28  0.0454  1.15    28.47   26.75   256.23
29  0.0456  1.27    27.05   26.52   256.95
30  0.0452  1.46    28.86   26.45   258.95
```

Code inside the loop compiles to this on gcc 9.3.1 with
`-O3 -march=native -fopenmp`.  `rax` starts from 0 and increases by 64
each iteration.  `rdx` points to `c[i]`.  `rsi` points to `b[j]`.  `rdi`
points to `b[j+1]`.

```
    vmovapd (%rsi,%rax), %ymm1
    vmovapd 32(%rsi,%rax), %ymm0
    vfmadd213pd (%rdx,%rax), %ymm3, %ymm1
    vfmadd213pd 32(%rdx,%rax), %ymm3, %ymm0
    vfmadd231pd (%rdi,%rax), %ymm2, %ymm1
    vfmadd231pd 32(%rdi,%rax), %ymm2, %ymm0
    vmovapd %ymm1, (%rdx,%rax)
    vmovapd %ymm0, 32(%rdx,%rax)
```

I wonder why the run time increases so much when the thread count
increases.

My estimate says this shouldn't be the case when `DIMENSION` is 4096.

What I thought before I remembered that the compiler does 2 `j` loops at
a time.  Each iteration of the `j` loop needs rows `c[i]` and `b[j]`.
They are 64KB in total.  My CPU has a 32KB L1 data cache and a 256KB L2
cache per 2 threads.  The four rows the two hardware threads are working
with don't fit in L1 but fit in L2.  So when `j` advances, `c[i]` is
read from L2.  When the program is run on 24 OS threads, the number of
involuntary context switches is around 29371.  Each thread gets
interrupted before it has a chance to finish one iteration of the `j`
loop.  Since 8 matrix rows can fit in the L2 cache, the other software
thread's 2 rows are probably still in L2 when it resumes.  So the
execution time shouldn't be much different from the 12 thread case.
However measurements say it's 4 times as slow.

Now that I have realized 2 `j` loops are done at a time.  This way each
`j` iteration works on 96KB of memory.  So 4 of them can't fit in the
256KB L2 cache.  To verify this is what slows the program down, I
compiled the program with `-fno-loop-unroll-and-jam`.  I got

```
    vmovapd ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rcx+rax]
    vfmadd213pd ymm0, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdx+rax]
    vmovapd YMMWORD PTR [rdx+rax], ymm0
```

The results are in the table.  They are like when 2 rows are done at a
time.  Which makes me wonder even more.  When `DIMENSION` is 4096, 4
software threads' 8 rows fit in the L2 cache when each thread works on 1
row at a time, but 12 rows don't fit in the L2 cache when each thread
works on 2 rows at a time.  Why are the run times similar?

I thought maybe it's because the CPU warmed up when running with less
threads and has to slow down.  I ran the tests multiple times, both in
the order of increasing thread count and decreasing thread count.  They
yield similar results.  And `dmesg` doesn't contain anything related to
thermal or clock.

I tried separately changing 4096 columns to 4104 columns and setting
`OMP_PROC_BIND=true OMP_PLACES=cores`, and the results are similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem seems to come from either the **CPU caches** (due to the bad *memory locality*) or the **OS scheduler** (due to more threads than the hardware can *simultaneously* execute).

I cannot exactly reproduce the same effect on my i5-9600KF processor (with 6 cores and 6 threads) and with a matrix of size 4096x4096. However, similar effects occur.

Here are performance results (with GCC 9.3 using `-O3 -march=native -fopenmp` on Linux 5.6):

```
#threads | time (in seconds)
----------------------------
       1 | 16.726885
       2 | 9.062372
       3 | 6.397651
       4 | 5.494580
       5 | 4.054391
       6 | 5.724844  <-- maximum number of hardware threads
       7 | 6.113844
       8 | 7.351382
       9 | 8.992128
      10 | 10.789389
      11 | 10.993626
      12 | 11.099117
      24 | 11.283873
      48 | 11.412288
```

We can see that the computation time starts to significantly grow between 5 and 12 cores.

This problem is due to a lot more data fetched from the RAM. Indeed, 161.6 Gio are loaded from memory with 6 threads while 424.7 Gio are loaded with 12 threads! In both cases, 3.3 Gio are written to the RAM. Because my memory throughput is roughly 40 Gio/s, the *RAM accesses represent more than 96% of the overall execution time* with 12 threads!

If we dig deeper, we can see that the number of L1 cache references and L1 cache misses are the same whatever the number of threads used. Meanwhile, there are a lot more L3 cache misses (as well as more references). Here are L3-cache statistics:

```
With 6 threads:     4.4 G loads
                    1.1 G load-misses  (25% of all LL-cache hits)

With 12 threads:    6.1 G loads
                    4.5 G load-misses  (74% of all LL-cache hits)
```

This means that the locality of the memory access is clearly worse with more threads. I guess this is because the compiler is not clever enough to do high-level cache-based optimizations that could reduce RAM pressure (especially when the number of threads is high). You have to **do tiling yourself** in order to improve the **memory locality**. You can find a good guide [here](https://gist.github.com/nadavrot/5b35d44e8ba3dd718e595e40184d03f0).

Finally, note that using more threads that the hardware can *simultaneously execute* is generally *not efficient*. One problem is that the OS scheduler often badly place threads to core and frequently move them. The usual way to fix that is to **bind software threads to hardware threads** using `OMP_PROC_BIND=TRUE` and set the `OMP_PLACES` environment variable. Another problem is that the threads are executed using *preemptive multitasking* with shared resources (eg. caches).

---

PS: please note that **BLAS libraries** (eg. OpenBLAS, BLIS, Intel MKL, etc.) are much more optimized than this code as most they already include clever optimization including manual vectorization for the target hardware, loop unrolling, multithreading, tiling and fast matrix transpositions when needed. For a 4096x4096 matrix, they are about 10 times faster.

Comment: Thanks.  The reason your slow down is less than mine could be because I
only have 1 DIMM installed.  How did you measure cache hits and misses?
I used `perf stat -e mem_load_retired.l3_hit,mem_load_retired.l3_miss`,
but I don't know if it's the right way.  I got 1.5G hits and 0.36G
misses on 12 threads and 1.2G hits and 3.3G misses on 18 threads.  And
do you have any insights as to why the L3 miss rate increases?  I tried
separately changing 4096 columns to 4104 columns and setting
`OMP_PROC_BIND=true OMP_PLACES=cores`, and the results are similar.

Comment: @izmw1cfg I used `perf stat -e LLC-load-misses,LLC-loads`. Note the value should be multiplied by the size of a cache-line to get the amount of data. They seems to be different to `mem_load_retired.l3_*` but the conclusion is the same. The matrices do not fit in the L3 cache and `b` it is reloaded from RAM for each `i` value! When you have more threads, I guess the accesses look like random ones from the L3 point-of-view and since matrices are too big, the miss rate increases. I advise you to use `OMP_PLACES="{0},{1},..."` which is a bit different (but I do not think this is the main problem).